# How to interpret Spearman correlation in R when it's different from Excel

Tags: r, excel, correlation

I've been running some correlations in R and in Excel, and since I'm getting very different results on the same data I'm very confused as to what is actually correct. I want to run the correlation on larger data in R, so the excel analysis was just to get some idea of what to expect, but now I don't trust myself with R on this.

Here is the data and results

```
X  Y
1  166
2  197
3  172
5  169
6  173
6  237
7  389
8  232
8  208

cor.test(X, Y, method="spearman")

S = 34.283, p-value = 0.03062
alternative hypothesis: true rho is not equal to 0
sample estimates:
      rho 
0.7143109
```

But according to excel (using "correl"), the correlation between these is around 0.48. Is that supposed to correspond to the S or the rho, or something else that I'm missing?

Comment: What does the excel help tell you about how the results are calculated?

Comment: good question, I can't copy the equation because it's an image but it's here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/correl-function-995dcef7-0c0a-4bed-a3fb-239d7b68ca92

Comment: Side note that Excel also has the `PEARSON` function, perhaps more obvious than `CORREL`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr** it looks like Excel is giving you the Pearson correlation, not the Spearman correlation.  (This is in fact exactly what the help page you linked is saying, although it never uses the word "Pearson".  How did you conclude that `method = "spearman"` was the right match for what Excel was computing ... ?)

`cor.test(d$X,d$Y)` (I saved the data frame as `d`)  gives

```
    Pearson's product-moment correlation

data:  d$X and d$Y
t = 1.4448, df = 7, p-value = 0.1918
alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.2711667  0.8673254
sample estimates:
      cor 
0.4792647
```

Comment: ah, that makes sense actually, I guess I was naive in thinking that it somehow knew which one was appropriate... will investigate further whether I can force spearman out of it

Comment: https://www.real-statistics.com/correlation/spearmans-rank-correlation/

Comment: https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2019/01/30/spearman-rank-correlation-excel/ this page is probably what confused me because they show the same formula for pearson and spearman, just using different data (actually so does the link you posted I think?)

Comment: yes. The Spearman is exactly the Pearson correlation computed by substituting ranks for the original data.

Comment: ok, will work on this further, thanks